# Binomial Power Series Expansion

Tags: power-series, binomial-theorem

I have learned how to expand linear expressions to negative and fractional powers but I'm not sure how to expand when they are of degree 2 or more.

Expand

$$\sqrt{1-x-x^2}$$
$$\sqrt{1+x+x^2}$$

I tried completing the square but wasn't sure what to do after that.

Comment: Have you tried letting $y = -x -x^2$ and $y = x + x^2$ respectively?

Comment: Equation 14.7.19 http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.7.E19